# Google Cloud, Server For Database

Tags: python, mysql, json, google-cloud-platform, server

I'm trying to use Google Cloud to store a MySQL database online which I can make requests to from my device in Python. I've established the connection with the database but I'm not sure where to go from here? Is it now 'saved' on the server, how would I go about accessing it from, say, a normal python module? Beginner in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Google search for tutorials on Python and MySQL.

Comment: Can you describe which service do you use on Google Cloud, and where you are stuck with the code that you have already written?